# How do I install libfcgi-dev package on Fedora 39 Workstation?

Tags: fedora

I could not find that over the internet. What could you say?

Comment: Available is : 'Google fgi github' → The are several "FGI"s . ...... Non existing is fgi-dev, libfgi-dev, lifgi-devel . (There have never been name-dev for Fedora. The Fedora naming is (lib)name-*devel* ).

Comment: Sorry, it's errata. I mean libfcgi-dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> install libfcgi-dev package on Fedora 39

"libfcgi-dev" is the Debian name for the fcgi "development package". (Debian clones like Mint, Ubuntu are also using this name.) Redhat Fedora is using the original name: `fcgi`.

1. Online search https://rpm.pbone.net/ → Advanced RPM Search
2. Search with the package manager:

   `dnf search fcgi-devel`

Install :  `# dnf install fcgi-devel`